# Custom Titlebar in a Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to create a (very) custom titlebar in a cocoa app. I read about the INAppStoreWindow library, but it seems it doesn't have the feature that I need. So here's what I have need to do (see image for clarification):

[image]

- My titlebar is the thing between the green and red circle
- The text (Text1 - Text3) are all images
- The black circle with the exclamation mark is also an image
- The grey area below the title bar is a webview. It expands from the left border all the way to the right edge of the reddish sidebar. (This is actually where why I think that the INAppStoreWindow won't work, as I cannot specify a width for the title bar)
- The images should have an Action

  - Text1 through Text3 as well as the black circle load some URL into the webview
  - Red circle closes the app

My app has no borders and no shadows. Right know in order to be able to move the app I drew a Box element at the top where the title bar should be. I think I can draw something in it as well, but as I'm very knew to cocoa development here are my questions:

- How can I draw some images in the Box element?
- Is there a better element to draw the titlebar in?

I know that are two questions, but they are closely relatated. It's generally: How to draw a simple titlebar like this?

As the problem inside the titlebar is the same for every item I need to draw (they are all images) I belive there is a quite simple solution for that, but because I lack the experience of how to solve this I'd need your help. You can also point me the the right direction in the comments and I'll answer this question myself after I've got it right.

Comment: It is hard to see what your problem is - you've clearly worked out how to turn off the title bar in a window, and looked through the selection of controls you can add and selected the Box. What else do you see in the list? How about the Image Well? The Custom View? Have you looked up `NSView` and the View Programming Guide? The Drawing Guide? Maybe you could design a custom view that draws a circle? After discovering the Box what stopped you going further?

Comment: You just have to get creative, because it seems like you pretty much have it worked out. Experiment with UITouch, UIButtons, UIImage, etc.

Comment: I was hoping for a quick answer like "you usually would do this like this: ...". That would same me time and hopefully also that of other people with a similar problem. Right now I'm checking out `colorWithPatternImage` with `setFillColor` in a `drawRect` method of a NSBox subclass. It's not working, but eventually I'll figure it out. This is for the grey background in the titlebar. Then I'll use NSImageView or the like for the other images. Will document this in an answer to this question then. But any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: @beipwale, For this thing you need to write your custom view class. On the top of that you can show whatever you required.

Comment: For your grey background look at subclassing `NSView` directly, not `NSBox` - you don't need anything from the latter and the former just gives you an empty view to do with what you will, fill with grey in your case.

Comment: All I get is a black background. I asked an isolated problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22681956/1146700)