# Setting the background of a custom view with an image results in a black background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, background, nsview

I have a problem setting the background of my subclassed NSView called `TitlebarView`. I want to use an image as a background via `colorWithPattternImage`, but the result is a black background not the image i gave the method as a parameter.

Here's my code of `TitlebarView`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSString* pathToTitlebarBGImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"titlebar_bg" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Resources/gui_images"];
        NSLog(@"path to titlebar bg image: %@", pathToTitlebarBGImage);
        //    NSString* pathToTitlebarBGImage = @"Resources/gui_images/titlebar_bg.png";
        self.titlebarBGImage = [NSImage imageNamed:pathToTitlebarBGImage];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:self.titlebarBGImage] setFill];
//    [[NSColor redColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

`titlebarBGImage` is a properly set property in the header files.
If I use the line with `redColor` I get the red colored view, so the code is working to some degree. For all I could find in the documentation an on stackoverflow this should actually work as intended. What am I missing here?

This is isolated problem of my overall question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22677259/1146700)

Comment: it seems, that my image is not loading  properly. The dimensions are 0,0. It's on the given path though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imageNamed:` takes a file name, not a path name, and searches for the file name in the bundle. If you wish to load an image from a path use `initWithContentsOfFile:`. See the [`NSImage` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect that `imageNamed` is that smart. I did also try `initWithContentsOfFile` but assigning it to the instance variable causes a warning: _Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment_  
`imageNamed` works fine though

Comment: You need to understand why that warning appeared, if you don't your Obj-C coding attempts will not fare well. In this case it suggests your property declaration is wrong and your code unsafe as a result. Go research memory management, ARC, strong, weak, unsafe.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As the `imageNamed` method worked I didn't bother too much. But you're absolutely right with your statement.